# What can and can't I be?

Tags: pattern, wordplay

> I cannot be a lego - but can be a lincoln log
>
> I cannot be false - but can be true
>
> I cannot be royalty - but can be regal
>
> I cannot be a tree - but can be a bushel
>
> I cannot be happy - but can be ___

Can you figure out the pattern and the next in the sequence?

Comment: Is `lincon log` or `lincoln log` ?

Comment: @lois6b No mistake on my part, sigh. And Lincoln log

Comment: By "the next in the sequence", do you mean finding an acceptable completion for the last statement in the puzzle, or finding a sixth statement that continues some pattern that extends across the five in the puzzle?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Could it be

> mad

Rationale:

> Lincoln log = Abraham Lincoln
> true = Harry S. Truman
> regal = Ronald Reagan
> bushel = George W. Bush
> mad = James Madison

Comment: Very nice.  This was correct!

Comment: ok, I'm clearly missing something obvious...but how does the third hint apllies?, I'm not seeing it

Comment: @Lamak: I am curious about that. The only thing I can think is that in certain accents atom and the word on the right of the equals may be pronounced the same...

Comment: The third one is quite a stretch

Comment: @Stume, can you edit, I changed the third line to clear it up.

Comment: @Jason_ Sure thing! Clever question - I happen to come from a place where we say atom with a 'd' ;)

Answer (score 2):

The answer might be:

> Satisfied

Because:

Lego vs Lincoln Log:

> Lincoln logs are similar to Legos but came first

False vs True:

> I suppose True came before False

Cell vs Atom:

> Atoms make Cells and came first

Tree vs Bushel:

> I'm not completely sure

Happy vs ___

> I said satisfied because you have to be satisfied to be happy.

Comment: Well, cells are made of atoms but with the bushel is the other way around - you cut a tree and make it into planks, and then use them to make a bushel.

Comment: @RadoslavHristov yeah I know, that's the only part that threw me off

Comment: I'm sure you do. Even with the rest I can see some vague similarity but the general picture just evades me.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps :

> One or the other

Because :

> Seems to be to be quite a contrary pattern though .. Meaning you cannot be both at the same time.. Unlike for example, Cold & Smelly.. That can be perfectly acceptable.

So given that  I would guess the answer to the last one is :

> Sad ?